# How to get a regular form field to autocomplete a geosearch with Leaflet's Geosearch plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, leaflet

I'm trying to get a regular form field used for searching for an address to autocomplete its values, as seen on [this page](https://www.veryfrenchgangsters.com/include/asset/leaflet-geosearch/docs/#search), using [Leaflet Geosearch](https://smeijer.github.io/leaflet-geosearch/usage) plugin.

So far the documentation says it can be binded to a form. Jquery UI's autocomplete looks like it can accomplish this, however i have not been able to wrap my head around how to do it.

I have successfully linked the form field to the geosearch provider, and it returns an array that can be seen in the browser console. I can algo get the autocomplete plugin to work, but with a local array, not the one produced by the geosearch plugin.

Here is an example of both plugins in action separately:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Leaflet tests</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<style type="text/css"> #mapid { height: 500px; width: 500px}</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-geosearch@3.0.0/dist/geosearch.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-geosearch@3.0.0/dist/geosearch.umd.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="mapid"></div>

<hr>

<div class="">
  <label for="search">geosearch field (check console): </label>
  <input id="search">
</div>

<div class="">
  <label for="search2">autocomplete field (apple or banana): </label>
  <input id="search2">
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 //code for generating map below
 var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
  subdomains: ['a','b','c']
}).addTo(mymap);

//code for search form below
const providerform = new GeoSearch.OpenStreetMapProvider();
const input = document.querySelector('input[id="search"]');
input.addEventListener('input', async (event) => {
  const results = await providerform.search({ query: input.value });
  console.log(results[0]); // » [{}, {}, {}, ...]
});
//
let fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana']

$("#search2").autocomplete(
    {
        source: fruits,
        delay: 100,
        minLength: 1
    });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd greatly appreciate any pointers in the right direction on how to get the autocomplete to work with the geosearch provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, but I don't know how to check at the moment because https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ is currently not working.

```js
$('#search2').autocomplete({
  source(request, response) {
    const providerform = new GeoSearch.OpenStreetMapProvider({
      params: {
        limit: 5
      }
    });
    return providerform.search({ query: request.term }).then(function (results) {
      response(results);
    });
  },
  delay: 100,
  minLength: 1
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! A quick question, how does the autocomplete plugin knows which value from the array to show? It correctly shows the label values.

Comment: If you analyze the example from [custom-data](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)
then you will see the data is taken from the label element by default.
The same is the case with Leaflet.GeoSearch and the object with the label element is also returned there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one basic example using jquery, there are other options too

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input[id="search2"]');
input.addEventListener('input', async (event) => {
  const results = await providerform.search({ query: input.value });
  console.log(results[0]); // » [{}, {}, {}, ...]
});

let fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana']

$("#search2").autocomplete(
    {
        source: fruits,
        delay: 100,
        minLength: 1
    });
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/resources/demos/style.css">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<hr>
<h1> Autocomplerde demo </h1>

<div class="">
  <label for="search2">autocomplete field (apple or banana): </label>
  <input id="search2">
</div>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
 
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, however in your snippet the geosearch field is not working, only the local array